# Are all the "Magic" methods on the JVM marked as Native?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface, native, bytecode

By "Magic" I mean the methods which have semantics which are not expressed in pure Java.

I know all `native` methods are magic, in that their implementation is provided by the underlying runtime and not by Java bytecodes.

Is the reverse true? Are all magic methods `native`, or are there some magic methods apparently implemented in pure Java, but with some extra help from some JVM-special-casing?

The use case is that I want to modify the semantics of Java by instrumenting its bytecodes. All these magic methods are special cases which I will have to handle some way or another. The `native` ones are all obvious, but I was wondering if there are any unmarked magic methods I have to watch out and special case for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there are "magic" methods outside of native methods. Take a look at intrinsic methods - these methods are known to the JIT, which uses hand rolled implementations when a method is compiled, and include heavily called methods such as String.indexOf, [Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfLeadingZeros%28int%29), etc.

Take a look at [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques), under Intrinsics, for some details and how to determine which methods are intrinsified on your JVM. I'm not sure if injecting bytecode will turn off intrisification, but there is a DisableIntrinsic XX option you can use to disable selected intrinsics.

Comment: Do you have any links? Googling "JVM Intrinsic Methods" doesn't give me any useful results

Comment: I updated my post with a link. You'll have to examine the source to get the up to date list of methods, but this is relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

You may find that a lot of details have already been handled in [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). I would take a look at it before doing manual bytecode manipulation.

Comment: I've already looked at it. It doesn't do what I want, which is resource accounting and throttling for memory and CPU usage. It's kinda of an unusual project, not your standard pointcuts!