# Byte comparison uses so much CPU

Tags: c#

Well i have this function to compare Red, Blue, Green, and Alpha Pixels in an image comparison for loop comparing two images

Code:

```
var o = 255 - c1.A;
var t = tolerance < o ? o : tolerance;
var b = AreSimiliar(ref c1.B, ref c2.B, ref t);
var g = AreSimiliar(ref c1.G, ref c2.G, ref t);
var r = AreSimiliar(ref c1.R, ref c2.R, ref t);
if (b && g && r) continue;

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] 
private static bool AreSimiliar(ref byte v1, ref byte v2, ref double tolerance)
{
    var z = v1 - v2;
    var t = z > 0 ? z : -z;
    return t <= tolerance;
}
```

The problem is it uses so much CPU although no external code is being used, and testing narrowed it down to that code that causes the load.

Comment: I doubt it will be useful to optimize just this code. Likely any realistic optimization will require looking carefully at the surrounding code as well.

Comment: dont use ref on byte unless you want to change them ... your passing a pointer of 32 bit or 64 bit instead of 8 bits... in fact remove all ref from that method

Comment: Also, `tolerance` could be an int since the delta will be as well.

Comment: Using CPU just means its doing something. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you change the tolerance type into byte, at least for AreSimilar? Since you don't seem to use it for division, byte should do the job faster. Heck you could just XOR both images as byte array to find the difference, then run threshold operation on the difference image with tolerance array.

Answer (score 2):

try this instead

```
var o = 255 - c1.A;
var t = tolerance < o ? o : tolerance;
if (AreSimiliar(c1.B, c2.B, t) && 
    AreSimiliar(c1.G, c2.G, t) &&
    AreSimiliar(c1.R, c2.R, t)) continue;

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)] 
private static bool AreSimiliar(byte v1, byte v2, double tolerance)
{
    var z = v1 - v2;
    var t = z > 0 ? z : -z;
    return t <= tolerance;
}
```

this might be even better

```
        var o = 255 - c1.A;
        var t = tolerance < o ? o : tolerance;
        if (Abs(c1.B - c2.B) <= t) & //or &&
            Abs(c1.G - c2.G) <= t) & //or &&
            Abs(c1.R - c2.R) <= t)) continue;

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static int Abs(int d)
    {
        int y = (d >> 31);

        return (d ^ y) - y;
    }
```

Comment: Using `&&` to shortcircuit the actual calculation rather than the comparison of the results should speed it up nicely!

Comment: It would also be worthwhile profiling the opposite, of using `&` to avoid the branching that `&&` adds. The code in the question was the worse of both worlds (duplicate effort AND branching), but the work done in `AreSimilar` is neither large enough to make short-circuiting the no-brainer obvious choice nor small enough to make avoiding the branch the no-brainer obvious choice, so it would be worth profiling both with realistic data.

Comment: @JonHanna, agree, added another possible solution

Comment: Could it run faster if t is a byte so all comparisons are between bytes?

Comment: @Martheen byte - byte = int so what is best? casting a int to byte or keeping everything at int? good question benchmark would tell

Comment: The problem is after testing your code i still get 20~30% cpu usage and that is insanely high for an application

Comment: @AhmedT.Yousef you cannot achieve 0% and depend on the computer it is run and finally it depend what the application do. at that point it's up to you to find what else can be optimized. this answer is for this question only.

Answer (score 0):

make your code branch free

use native SIMD (avx,sse) code
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD

Comment: It's not clear what SIMD support .NET has; what steps are required by DEVs to enable it; and what types support it. http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/64-bit-simd-code-from-c/240168851 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906215/how-to-enable-simd-in-a-new-net-framework-4-6.  Quite exciting though