# Mono C#/C++ Interop, optimizing matrix multiplications - minimal gain due to overhead?

Tags: c#, c++, optimization, mono, pinvoke

I have a matrix struct on C# with the multiplications operations implemented without using SSE intrinsics. As I don't have access to the code at this very moment, I'll try to specify details as much as I can rather than copy/pasting the definition. I can edit the post in the morning to include relevant definitions if need be.

The struct has 16 `float`s defined as `M11, M12, M13, ..., M43, M44'` with the sequential layout specified: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`

The C++ function is declared with the attribute specification 
    `[DllImport("cppCode.dll", EntryPoint = "MatrixMultiply", CallingConvention = CallingConvention::Cdecl]`

I'm trying to make a call to a C++ function using P/Invoke for optimizing the multiplications. My question is about passing the parameters. As mentioned on MSDN, the cost is 10 to 30 cycles of CPU + marshalling if the type passed is not blittable.

The function call on C# looks like

```
MatrixMultiply(ref matrix1, ref matrix2, out matrix_out);
```

and the C++ counterpart receives them with `mat*`, with `mat` being the matching C++ struct with 4x `vec4`s.

```
static extern void MatrixMultiply(mat* m1, mat* m2, mat* out) { *out = *m1 * *m2; }
```

When the calculations are profiled, the gain is quite minimal - a microsecond or two - on the average case. However, the worst case became worse, from 150us with C# multiplication to 400us with C++ multiplication, which leads me to think that the overhead for calling a function from the exported dll almost eliminates the gain from SSE instructions.

As I have limited familiarity with C#, I can't tell for sure what's going on. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a faster approach for C#/C++ communication in this particular case?

Comment: You could use the types from [`System.Numerics.Vectors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858218(v=vs.111).aspx) which utilize SIMD. There's even a `Matrix4x4` class.

Comment: [Struct, I mean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.matrix4x4(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: @cubrr The [Matarix4x4 class doesn't support SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31907264/2034041) - I've checked disassembly to make sure -  it's on Vectors for now. So I've tried storing the C# matrix as 4 SIMD:Vec4's and implemented Matrix multiplication the naive way. Didn't have time to profile yet (so i'll know for sure tomorrow whether its faster or not), but I expect better performance with the same naive matrix multiplication the original implementation uses because we will be using SIMD registers.

Comment: Huh, well that's disappointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be minimizing the p/Invoke calls if Numerics won't provide a good enough solution. Instead of calling `Multiply(m1, m2, m_out)` for every multiplication, try to concatenate matrices in one call on the C++ side where possible like this:

```
void MatrixConcat3(m1, m2, m3, m_out);
void MatrixConcat4(m1, m2, m3, m4, m_out);
void MatrixConcat5(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m_out);
...
```

That would reduce the overhead of making multiple calls.