# Correct syntax to leverage SIMD-enabled types in System.Numerics?

Tags: c#, optimization, vectorization, simd

Fairly simple question but not so obvious in the end, look at the following example:

```
public void Test(float a, float b, float c, float d)
{
    // not SIMD-enabled since we multiply ourselves?
    var x = new Vector4(a * d, b * c, c * b, d * a);

    var y = new Vector4(a, b, c, d);
    var z = new Vector4(d, c, b, a);

    // gets SIMD-enabled as done by the intrisics?
    var w = y * y;
}
```

In the case of `x`, I'd assume it's incorrect as result is immediately computed and passed to `ctor`.

In the case of `w`, I'd assume it's right usage.

But I'm not sure in the end...

If one looks at the source code, there's the `Intrisic` non-public attribute:

```
[Intrinsic]
public Vector4(float x, float y, float z, float w)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    Z = z;
    W = w;
}
```

Maybe it does some magic under the hood, again, not sure.

**Question:**

Is the `x` syntax not leveraging SIMD but only `z` or `w` syntax are?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct

This one does its calculations *before* passing to the constructor, so is not using SIMD. That much is obvious from reading the code: `a` `b` `c` `d` are not Vectors, so no SIMD is being used.

```cs
var x = new Vector4(a * a, b * b, c * c, d * d); // not SIMD-enabled
```

---

The `*` operator and the `Multiply` function are marked `[Intrinsic]` because the [JIT optimizes them out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56392846/14868997) to use SIMD. You can use either of these.

```cs
var y = new Vector4(a, b, c, d);
var z = y * y; // SIMD-enabled
```

Comment: The answer is not entirely correct. The first case involving the Vector4 constructor also uses xmm registers when available (and therefore is also "SIMD-enabled", whatever this is supposed to mean): https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgDkBXfGKASzFwBuGjWIBmJqQYBhBgG8aDJUwkA1GGAzQUDALIAKAJSLlC6gDdsUBtgYBeBqzoAzYRasNg9hqRYu3ltZg3mJ+rjSBDAAm3ihhbqIA7AwAdjAA7gzqmtr6tgBUNmieDIXAxcGFYMUxhVGGbsoMAL4i1M1AA

Comment: That's interesting, basically we have it out of the box in some scenarios, that's why I wasn't seeing much difference in the throughput when profiled.

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins "SIMD-enabled" might mean [`​Vector.IsHardwareAccelerated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated).

Comment: @EyesShriveledToRaisins True but the actual multiplication is not done using SIMD. In this particular instance all the variables are inlined. Even when they are not inlined, SIMD register are used, but only one at a time https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgDkBXfGKASzFwBuGjWIBmJqQYBhBgG8aDJQwBmAGwjYMDbAwC8DVnRXDqy1Rq0Ng+hqRbHT59Zu1hbYhycXKXVgCa2KF5OyuIMAGowYBjQKAwAsgAUAJQ+SgrUogDsDAB2MADukdGxUChJugBUOmjWDDXAde41YHWBNf4poUoAviLUvUA

Comment: Compare with https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgDkBXfGKASzFwBuGjWIBmJqQYBhBgG8aDJQwBmAGwjYMDbAwC8DVnRXDqy1Rq0Ng+hqRbHT59Zu1hbYhycXKXVgCa2KF5OyuIMAGowYBjQKAwAsgAUAJQ+SgrUAG7YUAwAnrYAdjAA7pHRsVAoSdho1vVg9f4ppjl5AF62hQBUBYIMAPSDDADKAJIJACJwMEXYwGow/qIA7AwdoUoAviLU20A